# I would like to show an error message after a user clicks on a save button if the URL they entered was invalid. Using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to show an error message AFTER a user clicks on a save button.  The field that they need to complete is a URL link and it must be a valid url.. I have a working regex in place, I just have no clue how this is supposed to be done as I am very new to angular.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
             ng-click="save()">
            <spring:message code="journalist.social.submit.label"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"</span>
        </button>
             <span style="color: #d2232a;padding-left: 0px" class="btn"
                      ng-show="!canSave()">
                    <spring:message code="journalist.info.error.fill.all"/>
                </span>
```

And in my scripts (The save button only works if the canSave function is true):

```
        $scope.save = function () {
                    var res = [];
                    var files = [];
                    var ind = 0;
                    if ($scope.canSave()){ //save button should only work if the URL is valid
                    $scope.linkList.forEach(function (clip) {
                        if (!clip.link) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!CommonUtils.startsWithHttp(clip.link)) {
                            clip.link = CommonUtils.EMPTY_LINK + clip.link;
                        }
                        if (clip.imgData && clip.imgData.input) {
                            files.push({id: ind, file: clip.imgData.input, cropData: clip.imgData.cropData})
                            clip.logos = undefined;
                        }
                        ind = ind + 1;
                        res.push({
                            id: clip.id,
                            title: clip.title,
                            description: clip.description,
                            name: clip.name,
                            link: clip.link,
                            ordering: ind,
                            logoUrl: clip.logos ? clip.logos[clip.logoInd] : null
                        })

                    });

                    Journalist.updateClips(
                        files,
                        res,
                        $scope,
                        function (e) {
                            $scope.warningOnLocationChange = false;
                            Navigation.open($scope, ["journalist", "profile", "profile"]);
                        }
                    );
                };
                $scope.showUpload = function (clip) {
                    if(clip.link) {
                        clip.showUpload = true;
                    }
                };
            }}]
    );
```

If you think the condition I have in my script for the save() function is not right then by all means tell me otherwise.  How can I show an alert after the button is clicked? The alert shows before a URL is even entered (or as they are typing and will go away once the url is correct.) Thanks!